# Keras - Masking CNNs

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, convolutional-neural-network

I have a 3D tensor on which I apply 2D convolutions. Sometimes, this 3D is padded both in width and height to have a fixed size. How could I apply masking (like with RNNs) so that the gradients associated with the weights of these padded cells don't get updates while backpropagating the error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @StatsSorceress sorry for the late answer. Indeed I have. The solution is multiplying by a binary matrix after the convolution layer, containing 1s in the values you want to keep and 0s otherwise. The gradient will not propagate through the values that were multiplied by zero.